# Modelling a Simple Translational System

Tags: applied-mechanics, dynamics, systems-engineering, linear-systems

I posted this on stack exchange physics, sadly no one has answered so I thought I'd try my luck here.

I am trying to model the following translational mechanical system in I/O form, however I am unable to see how the force of the damper b12 is affected the force on M2. The damper b12 reduces the net force on M1, I understand that, however, I am struggling to see why it pushes M2 hence causing M2 to move with a velocity v2.

[image]

I think I have modelled the system correctly, however, I don't understand the physics of it. Below are my coupled differential equations for M1 and M2.

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: first step: draw free body diagrams, for both M1 and M2

Comment: When the force is applied to M1, the damper will provide a resistant force of k*s, k is the stiffness of the damper (F/L), and s is the displacement of the damper (L). So, the equation of this force system is F1 - k*s = F2 (force on M2). You can write the equation expressed in energy terms too.

Comment: what does the damper b1 and b2 represent? Is it the coulomb friction between the masses and the ground? Some sort of viscous friction?

Comment: @r13 - that would be for a spring, wouldn't it? first approximation of damper shown, would be $F$ proportional to $v$ (ie d/dt of the extension)

Comment: @PeteW Yes. IMO, the force from M1 is reduced/dampened by the damper but can't stop it, the balance is carried by M2.